# Looping through pandas' dataframe rows and compare values on columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Many thanks in advance. I am python newbie and this was a bit harder than I thought.

I have an array [m, n] where m are the names of players (0-9) and n are years (A-E). I have marked each row with a "1" signifying if that player was taken into the previous team game ("0" if they were not). I would like to create a few groupings/classes given this.

```
  A B C D E
0 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0 0
2 0 0 1 1 1
3 1 1 1 1 1
4 0 1 1 0 0
5 0 1 1 1 0
6 1 1 0 1 1
7 0 0 0 0 1
8 1 0 1 1 0
9 1 1 0 1 1
```

Some edits on the classes:
1. First time in team (a)
2. Still in tema and been consecutively for past years (b)
3. Still in team but on and off (c)
4. Not in team but been there before (d)
5. Never made it to team (e)

The idea is to have functions for each of the classes that are later compiled into one function.

For example, here is a sample code for Class a:

```
class_a=[]
for (i, row) in test.iterrows():
    if (test.iloc[i, -1]==1):
        if (test.iloc[i, 0:-2].sum(axis=0))==0:
            class_a.append('Yes')
```

However, sample code for Class b is a bit more difficult:

```
test1=[]
count=0

for (i, row) in test.iterrows():
    row = test.iloc[i, 0:-1]
    for j in range(0, len(row)-1):
        if row[j]>=row[j+1]:
            print(i, row[j], row[j+1], 'Yes')
            count+=1
print(count)
```

When I print the result of i, row[j] and row[j+1], I get the following values which cannot be right. I am deducing that the interation on the row values is not right as I am missing an index across the rows (the j value). The count seems to be ok (even though is counting the wrong thing):

```
0 1 0 Yes
0 0 0 Yes
1 1 0 Yes
1 1 0 Yes
2 0 0 Yes
2 1 1 Yes
3 1 1 Yes
3 1 1 Yes
3 1 1 Yes
4 1 1 Yes
4 1 0 Yes
5 1 1 Yes
5 1 1 Yes
6 1 1 Yes
6 1 0 Yes
7 0 0 Yes
7 0 0 Yes
7 0 0 Yes
8 1 0 Yes
8 1 1 Yes
9 1 1 Yes
9 1 0 Yes
22
```

Any help and pointers are greatly appreciated. I did think of using arrays but it is complicated as the value is on each of the rows, not the columns. Am I thinking wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is through the use of pandas DataFrame.apply. For each group You start by creating a function that tells you if a player is in the group or not based on his history, and then you apply this function of each row. For instance, for your first example, you could define :

```
def first_time_in_team(series):
    return( (series.iloc[:-1].max()==0) and (series.iloc[-1]==1))
```

This function returns True if the player was not in the team until this year and in the team this Year, and false in the other case. 
Then you would do :

```
group_first_time = df.apply(first_time_in_team,axis = 1)
```

where df is a dataframe containing your array.
This would give you a series with index the list of the player and a column with value True if the player if is the group and false otherwise. You can then adapt the first function to fit each group.

Comment: Thank you, that was a great way to do it without looping (that was my first choice). I get, however, false för all the rows in the last column [-1].

Comment: Here is the code: series = Team_df.iloc[:,1:-1]

def first_time_in_team(series):
    return((series.iloc[:-1].max()==0) and (series.iloc[-1]==1))

group_first_time = Team_df.apply(first_time_in_team, axis=1)

group_first_time

Comment: I wonder if there's a , missing on the indexing somewhere in your code. Shouldn't it be: series.iloc[:, :-1].max()==0. A bit confused. Thank you!